# Populate tables on Plugin install

Tags: plugin-development

I'm using [Records](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records) to create some new tables for use by my plugin. I now need to add some initial data to one of the these tables. What's the best way of accomplishing this on install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like overriding the `onAfterInstall()` method in the main Plugin class is where I should be adding this sort of stuff. Amazing what you find when you actually read the instructions!

More details [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#methods)